# Error when creating a List object in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, collections

I am new to .Net framework and I am getting an error message

> Value of type 'List(Of AdminSetEmployeeParams)' cannot be converted to
>   'AdminSetEmployeeParams'"

```
Dim SetNewEmployee As New List(Of AdminSetEmployeeParams)

  SetNewEmployee.Add(New AdminSetEmployeeParams With {
                    .departmentId = ddlDept.SelectedValue,
                    .familyName = txtLastOrSurname.Text,
                    .firstName = txtFirstOrGivenName.Text,
                    .secondName = txtSecondName.Text,
                    .contactPhone = txtPhone.Text,
                    .user = ""})

SetNewEmployee = EmployeeAPIService.AdminSetEmployee(SetNewEmployee).Result
```

How would I resolve this error?

Update:

```
System.Threading.Tasks
Public Class Task(Of TResult)


Public ReadOnly Property Result As TResult
```

Comment: Ignoring the error for a moment, the code doesn't really make sense as it is.  You declare variable, create a new `List` and assign it to that variable, add an item to the `List` and then you discard that `List` altogether by assigning something else to the variable.  Is that last line assigning to the wrong variable?  If not, what's the point of creating a new `List` and adding an item to it if you're just going to throw it away?

Comment: As for the error message, it's telling you that `EmployeeAPIService.AdminSetEmployee(SetNewEmployee).Result` is type `AdminSetEmployeeParams` but you're assigning it to a variable of type `List(Of AdminSetEmployeeParams)`.  That's like trying to put an egg where an egg carton is expected.  That's why I wonder whether assigning to that variable is what you actually want to do.  Should actually be `SetNewEmployee.Add(EmployeeAPIService.AdminSetEmployee(SetNewEmployee).Result)`?  Should you be assigning to a different variable? Try explaining what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, if that's a run-time exception then that means that you must have `Option Strict Off`, which is bad.  You should set `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so it will be `On` by default in future.  Issues like this will then be flagged at design time rather than run time.

Comment: To respond to your 2nd comment... I am attempting to pass a collection to an API that was created by someone else (this is known not to be the best design, but right now I need to pass data to the API)

Comment: when implementing the code in your 2nd comment, I get this error Value of type 'List(Of AdminSetEmployeeParams)' cannot be converted to 'AdminSetEmployeeParams'

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this, but it's hard to be sure:

```
Dim newEmployee As New AdminSetEmployeeParams

newEmployee = New AdminSetEmployeeParams With {
                .departmentId = ddlDept.SelectedValue,
                .familyName = txtLastOrSurname.Text,
                .firstName = txtFirstOrGivenName.Text,
                .secondName = txtSecondName.Text,
                .contactPhone = txtPhone.Text,
                .user = ""})

Dim newEmployeeResult As List(Of AdminSetEmployeeParams) = EmployeeAPIService.AdminSetEmployee(newEmployee).Result
```

I'm not sure why your API returns a list of employees in its result (I'm assuming it does because you don't say you have an error message complaining about the assignment of the result to a list(of...) ) but the error as given would reasonably only occur if the API call demanded a single new employee and you handed it a list of new employees

If it doesn't work out, try this last line

```
Dim newEmployeeResult As AdminSetEmployeeParams = EmployeeAPIService.AdminSetEmployee(newEmployee).Result
```

And if that doesn't work out, edit your question to give more info on what kind of arguments `AdminSetEmployee` takes and what kind of object .`Result` is

Comment: in your last line, 
I am getting this error on the code line "EmployeeAPIService.AdminSetEmployee(newEmployee).Result"
Value of type 'List(Of AdminSetEmployeeParams)' cannot be converted to 'AdminSetEmployeeParams'

Comment: unfortunately I am not privileged to format the comments section  :-(

Comment: You can try dropping the `As List(Of AdminSetEmployeeParams)` from the last line, and let type inference do its thing, provided that the return value from the API is strongly-typed (this doesn't work if it's declared as type `Object`---or rather, it gives you a result which is itself of type `Object` which you'll then need to cast, but then it's still probably better to cast explicitly and leave the declaration inferred).

Comment: @dotNetRookie so what is your service returning? A single employee params or a list of employee params? I guessed at the return value because you didn't say it was causing an error (but now you do say it causes an error)

Comment: It's not returning anything except a success message. The API is to save Employee record to the db....  and I am passing one record at a time. As I mentioned, the API was created by someone else.

Comment: I meant specifically what type of object .Result is - a string? A boolean? a AdminSetEmployeeParams?

Comment: The code posted only shows that Result is some generic type. Run the code in a debugger, call the service and tell us what the actual type of .Result is at runtime